# How do I upgrade PHP from 7.2 to 7.3 using the yum command on CentOS?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, yum, php-7.3

I am running an EC2 server on AWS and I was looking into upgrading php from 7.2 to 7.3. However, all the tutorials I found were on Ubuntu and they all used the `apt` command instead of `yum`.

I also ran the command `cat /etc/os-release` to find out what the operating system of my server is and the ID_LIKE line said `ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"`.

I found instructions on the upgrade that are relatively simple on Ubuntu.
Does anyone know how I would translate the following commands for CentOS using `yum` instead of `apt` on Ubuntu?

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3
```

Comment: The specific commands you will need would vary based on specific CentOS version and which repositories you used to install the PHP 7.2. Can you post the output of `cat /etc/redhat-release`, `yum repolist` and `yum list installed | grep php`?

Answer (score 5):

In CentOS you have to enable the extra epel repository first and change the php version.

```
sudo yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm 
sudo yum -y install epel-release yum-utils

sudo yum-config-manager --disable remi-php54
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
```

Then you should be able to install the new php version. Try `yum update` or reinstall the packages.

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-centos-7-fedora/